# Which `vboxmanage clonehd` variant corresponds to the GUI selection `dynamically allocated`?

Tags: command-line, virtualbox

I wanted to resize a VMDK, which `VBoxManage` can't resize directly, so I used the Convert to VDI → Resize VDI → Convert to VMDK procedure described [here](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=50661#p264732).

For the last step, I could not find clear documentation of which `--variant` corresponded to the "dynamically allocated" option I chose in the GUI when creating the original VMDK.

The [documentation on `clonehd`](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-clonevdi) has this list of variants: Standard, Fixed, Split2G, Stream, ESX.  It is not obvious from the names which of those is dynamically allocated, and there is no mention of which variants apply to which image formats.

The [documentation on disk image files](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch05.html#vdidetails) refers to the GUI options of "fixed-size" or "dynamically allocated", but uses the word "variant" to mean file format, and does not refer to the list above or any of its entries.

**Which `--variant` corresponds to selecting "dynamically allocated" in the GUI?**

This is with VirtualBox 5.0.32 r112930 on macOS Sierra 10.12.3 (16D32)

Comment: There is a relevant discussion in [this forum thread](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=39404), but it's old, doesn't have a clear answer, doesn't link the documentation it quotes, and devolves into pointless arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [forum post](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=24725&start=0#p110232):

- Standard (the default) - one piece dynamic (sparse) extent file, plus a small descriptor file.
- Fixed - extents will be flat (rather than dynamic/sparse).
- Split2G - image is split into multiple extents, each less than 2GB.
- Stream - image is optimized for streaming downloads rather than running in a VM. This type may be compressed.
- ESX ?

so *standard* is you proper option or **no** *--variant* at all since *standard* is the default.

Comment: Having created the disk and seen the file size much smaller than the increased capacity, it looks like your conclusion is correct.  But where the heck did they find that information?